# RubyMonk - I/O Stream - "Too many open files"

Tags: ruby, io, stream

I'm on RubyMonk Book 1 Ch 9.1 The default code to demonstrate a concept is this. How do I close the open files? Apparently I ran this too many times after coming back to it and it now returns this error:

```
# open the file "new-fd" and create a file descriptor:
fd = IO.sysopen("new-fd", "w")

# create a new I/O stream using the file descriptor for "new-fd":
p IO.new(fd)

STDOUT:
class: Errno::EMFILE
message: Too many open files - new-fd
backtrace: RubyMonk:4:in `sysopen'
```

EDIT: Apparently the site is emulating file creation/deletion using FakeFS.  This contributes to unusual behavior such as calling IO.methods not returning anything.  Link to site: https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/42-introduction-to-i-o/lessons/89-streams

Comment: Have you tried `File.close` or something similar?

Comment: This is my first time working with I/O so I had not tried that.  Trying it returns an undefined method error (probably because it is only emulating I/O).  Edited to include link to site.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things here:

- leaking file handles: if you keep opening files and don't close the handles/descriptors you get you will eventually run out of handles. The number of files you can have open per machine/processes is usually limited (and if you do leak you will eventually exhaust them). the solution is to stop the leak and properly clean up after you're done with files.
- needing more file handles that your system currently allow you to have: In the case you legitimately need to have a high number of files opened simultaneously you can run into the limit mentioned above even if you are not leaking thing. In this case I would recommend you look into what the limits are and maybe adjusting them. Start by googling "ulimit linux" (for example: http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html)